# Scope for Agent Pool (DistributedTask) in Javascript REST Client in TFS 2015.3

Tags: javascript, rest, tfs

I'm trying to get agent pool information on TFS 2015.3 (such as name of agent pool, how many agents in pool) through the Javascript REST API client. I was able to perform this action through PowerShell and open the API call in a browser tab to see JSON content, but I'm getting a 401 (unauthorized) message when going through Javascript with an extension.

I've added the vso.profile and vso.build scopes but it doesn't look like that makes a difference. I found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/issues/18) for the exact same problem but look like it's going unanswered for a few months.

```
VSS.require(["VSS/Controls", "VSS/Controls/Grids","VSS/Controls/Dialogs",
         "VSS/Service", "TFS/DistributedTask/TaskAgentRestClient"],
         function (Controls, Grids, Dialogs, VSS_Service, RestClient) {
        var client = RestClient.getClient();

        client.getAgentPools().then(function(agentPools)
        {
            jQuery.each(agentPools,function(index, agentPool)
            {
                $("#agentBody").append("<td>"+agentPool.properties.name+"</td>");
            })
        }).catch(console.log.bind(console));
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
     });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could this work with your personal VSTS?

Comment: Just tried it now, looks like I still get a 401 unauthorized. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try some other  module path also belong to distributed task such as  `TFS/DistributedTask/TaskRestClient` https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/distributedtask/taskrestclient/taskhttpclient2_1 . Usually if you can work with powershell, then should also be able with javascript in the extension.

Comment: Yep, can work with PowerShell, but getting a 401 with the extension in Javascript.